# how do I send selected uitableview rows to a newly created group

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I cannot find any information on this. I want to send my selected rows(ones that have checkmarks) into my firebase database as a newly created group. I have created a "Create group" button outside of my tableview. I would love to have some more information or resources on how to pass data from selected rows but I have not been able to find anything on the topic. I see a lot of information on how to select and deselect a row with a checkmark, but nothing on sending the information from the selected checkmarked rows to an array or an online database in my case.

```
class FriendsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

 var userList = [Users]()

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

@IBAction func createGroup(_ sender: Any) {
}
final let urlString = "https://api.lookfwd.io/v1/test/users"

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return userList.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    myCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
    myCell.nameLabel.text = userList[indexPath.row].name
    return myCell
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.downloadJsonWithTask()

}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark{

        myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none}
    else{
        myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    }

            }



func downloadJsonWithTask() {

    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

    var downloadTask = URLRequest(url: (url as URL?)!, cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 20)

    downloadTask.httpMethod = "GET"

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadTask, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let response = data {
            if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any] {

                if let dataArray = (jsonData as AnyObject).value(forKey: "users") as? [[String:Any]] {
                    for data in dataArray{
                        let newUser = Users(data: data)
                        self.userList.append(newUser)
                        print(jsonData!)
                    }
                }
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    for use in self.userList {
                        print(use.name ?? "")
                    }
                    self.myTableView.reloadData()

                })

                print(jsonData!)
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your users objects are stored in array `userList`. You simply need to record clicked index like thid

```
var selected = [String]()
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark{
        myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
        let currentUser = userList[indexPath.row]
        selected = selected.filter { $0 != currentUser.name}
    }else{
        myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
        let currentUser = userList[indexPath.row]
        selected.append(currentUser.name)
    }
}
```

After that, when every you want to get all selected names

```
for username in self.selected{
    print(username ?? "")
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on how to get my name element from userList by indexes from selected array?

Comment: @user8000557 Loop through `selected` array, get `User` object from `userList` array by index, and then get name from each User``

Comment: @IBAction func createGroup(_ sender: Any) {
        for (selected, name) in userList.enumerated(){
            print(selected, name)
        }
    }

Comment: @user8000557 You only need add the names? Or all the user Objects?

Comment: I only need the names, ill be adding just the names to a group into my firebase database

Comment: @user8000557 Updated answer